# Arduino Stepper and Driver Frequencies and limitations

Tags: c, arduino-uno, stepper

I have been using an Arduino Uno for running a stepper on the pulse side of things.

I have found a limitation of what I presume to be the stepper driver, or Uno Hardware limitation etc.

I have been using this basic bit of code to figure the correct settings for my application, ie higher RPM motor actuation, setting the timing to delay(0.9) in the code below seems to meet the limitations of something on my setup, I believe that my cheap Foyo FYM404A driver to be the culprit.

it says that the frequency limitation is 100kpps, (100,000Hz?).

when measuring at the 0.9 setting with a digital multimeter (gnd to pin 9) the frequency reads 75.48KHz.
this setting is when im hearing a whining noise and no motion of the motor

when repeating the measurement when set to delay(1) it reads 495.80Hz and a good stable running of the motor.

What I am trying to figure out is whether the jump in frequency seems right to you? going from delay(1 to 0.9)

and

whether it could be entirely possible that the limitation is with the stepper driver and it just isn't able run at higher frequencies or the code isn't using the full capability of the Uno which from what I read can pulse to 8MHz, when programmed properly.

looking forward to your constructive answer.

```
 void loop() {
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH); // sets the digital pin 8 on
  delay(1);            //  waits for .1 second's
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);  // sets the digital pin 8 off
  delay(1);            // waits for .1 second's
}
```

Comment: Consider posting this at [arduino.se] or maybe [electronics.se].

Comment: This is a step towards the right answer https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19961/maximum-frequency-of-digital-signal-in-arduino-uno

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about Arduino tools and not about programming. It belongs on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: figured the programming might be the issue, hence my post on here?

Comment: @Lundin the answer to this question might be in the performance of the digitalWrite or sleep function, hence I don't see any difference with other questions relative to code performance depending on the hardware.

Comment: @Fra93 Still that would be a question about a specific Arduino lib, also better asked at the Arduino site.

Comment: _"figured the programming might be the issue"_...   Not enough programming included here to know if there _is_ a problem.  As shown this has little to do with language, more to do with Arduino.  Agreeing with others suggesting to post on the Arduino cite.

Comment: I have read else where that you can better utilise the use of the hardware to reach 8MHz, via better programming.

Answer (score 0):

The delay function accepts integer value, not floating-point values, this means passing '0.9' to the function will be actually translated as '0' by the compiler as the compiler do cut/truncate the decimal part of the number and keep only the integer part which is '0' in this case.

delay function takes its input argument as milliseconds, which means if you want to have a frequency of 5HZ (i.e. 0.1 sec LOW and 0.1 sec HIGH -> f= 1/0.2) you should be calling delay(100) -> 100ms = 0.1sec

Comment: Thank you. just to clarify, 1 is the highest setting this function would take due to the fact that it will not recognise floating point numbers?. The higher the frequency the better as I need to pulse as quickly as possible. so there is no other way to get more out of this code?

Comment: 1 is the lowest yes (1ms) if you want less delay you should try the delayMicroseconds() function which will give you the ability to wait less time (I.e. more frequency)